# Finding an effective pattern to cache entities and reuse them across requests with EF Core

Tags: c#, caching, entity-framework-core

I'm not an Entity Framework expert and I'm still in the process of learning how to use it.

I'm facing an issue for which I don't understand if I'm choosing the wrong design or there is a simple solution instead.

This question refers to EF Core 8 specifically.

Consider these entities as an example of my scenario:

```
public class City
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;

    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; } = new List<Student>();
}

public class Student
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; } = default!;
    public int CityId { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
}
```

Suppose that the list of cities for this application doesn't change frequently. In this case, instead of reading cities from the database each time, it makes sense to read them once and keep them cached for a long time (e.g: 1 week).

The `ICityCache` service can be used to get a city entity from the configured caching layer (e.g: memory cache):

```
public interface ICityCache
{
    Task<City?> GetByName(string name, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

Finally, consider an action method used to create new `Student` entities, which uses the `ICityCache` service to read city entities from the cache and avoid additional database calls to fetch cities from the database:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/students")]
public class StudentsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ICityCache _cityCache;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public StudentsController(ICityCache cityCache, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _cityCache = cityCache;
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateStudentCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var city = await _cityCache.GetByName(command.City, cancellationToken);

        if (city is null)
        {
            return this.BadRequest("The specified City is unknown");
        }
    
        // if I don't add this line, the context tracks the city entity with Added state and it tries to INSERT the city when SaveChangesAsync is called 
        _context.Cities.Attach(city);

        var student = new Student
                          {
                              Name = command.Name,
                              Age = command.Age,
                              City = city,
                          };

        _context.Students.Add(student);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        return this.Ok(new { id = student.Id });
    }
}
```

This code works, but it has a problem. The `Students` property of the cached `City` entities keeps growing over time. As soon as the new `Student` entity is added to the context, then the `Student` entity is added to the collection of students for the cached `City` entity. Having these cached entities which are changed over time and which keeps growing is something I want to avoid.

How can I solve this problem ? Should I remove the `Students` navigation property from the `City` class altogether ? This is weird, since basically I'm changing an entity definition in order to solve a caching issue. Is there something more clever that I can do ?

Maybe I'm designing this code in the wrong way and this kind of entity reusing across different requests is something that EF Core isn't suited for ?

Comment: Instead of assigning `City` property, assign `CityId`, then attaching is not needed.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the way to fix this problem. This way the context doesn't track the City entity and so the City is not modified when the new Student object is created. Feel free to answer the question if you want and to elaborate a little more on this topic.

Comment: Also consider whether City even needs a Students navigation property. Student can be assigned a `.HasOne(x => x.City).WithMany();` for a unidirectional reference. Not all navigation properties need to be bi-directional, in general I recommend avoiding bi-directional unless it provides value. In the odd case where you want all students for a city, you can always query through the Student. (`context.Students.Where(x => x.City.Id == cityId);`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an implementation for a cache to consider to handle lookup entities that encapsulates the checks for the cache, attaching found cache entries to the applicable DbContext instance, and loading data if necessary. "AppDbContext" = your application DbContext, so if using an injected, request lifetime scoped DbContext, pass the current reference to the cache GetById/GetByName call.

```
public interface ILookupCache<TEntity> where TEntity: class // consider a contract interface for identifying supported lookup entities.
{
    TEntity GetById(AppDbContext context, int id);
    TEntity GetByName(AppDbContext context, string name);
}

// Singleton scoped
public class CityLookupCache : ILookupCache<City>
{
    private IList<City>? _cache = null;

    City ILookupCache<City>.GetById(AppDbContext context, int id)
    {
        var city = context.Set<City>()
            .Local()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        if (city != null) return city;

        if(_cache == null) refreshCache(context);
        city = _cache.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        if(city != null)
        { 
             context.Attach(city);
             return city;
        }

        city = context.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        if (city != null)
            _cache.Add(city);
        return city;
    }

    City ILookupCache<City>.GetByName(AppDbContext context, string name)
    {
        var city = context.Set<City>()
            .Local()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
        if (city != null) return city;

        if(_cache == null) refreshCache(context);
        city = _cache.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
        if(city != null)
        { 
             context.Attach(city);
             return city;
        }

        city = context.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
        if (city != null)
            _cache.Add(city);
        return city;
    }

    private void refreshCache(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _cache = context.Set<City>()
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Essentially what these calls do is manage a cache for a given lookup call. There is no explicit "Load" call to initialize the cache, it initializes on the first call. This uses a provided App DbContext passed in to allow the cache to function as a Singleton between requests. It internally handles that the found lookup is associated against the DbContext instance.

The first thing it will check is if the app DbContext is already tracking the requested city. If so, it just returns that instance, no cache check needed.

On the first call the cache will be empty so it will populate the cache with an AsNoTracking() query. For larger sets (thousands+ records) this step could be removed and just check cache or load+cache individual entries as requested if not in the cache. (see below step)

With an existing cache or the freshly loaded cache we find the item by ID or name and if found, attach it to the given DbContext instance and return it. If the item is not found in the cache then we will load it, add it to the cache, and return it. This handles the case where a city might be added since the cache was read.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the sample code. To fix the original problem described in the question, you suggest to remove the navigation property Students from entity City, correct?

Comment: I worked on a similar, but less elegant, approach and kept running into issues when the cached, non-tracked entities were connected to tracked entities. There were two common problems: 1) EF would begin tracking the cached entity, and eventually generate "primary key is already being tracked" errors and 2) data validation cycles triggering the "exceeded recursive validation limits" error. I was trying to use non-tracked cache entities, and I did not specifically add the cached entity to the context because many of my queries were non-tracked. Steve, would your approach prevent the problems?

Comment: @pjs, if you want to avoid such problems, always clone entities before attaching. Attaching gives control over entity instance to EF Core, which may change object, fix some properties. It is dangerous in multithreading environment.

Comment: @pjs: Yes, this approach helps prevent those types of issues. It centralizes the checks against the DbContext to first find and provide any existing tracked references which should be used before attempting to attach a different, untracked reference. However this only should be considered for association-type relationships, things like lookup tables where the cached values do not change. It doesn't help other situations where more parent-child relationships of editable data are passed around between DbContext instances. There you need to do something similar but find & update values vs attach.

Comment: @Enrico: If you do not need the navigation property at all then setting the FK alone will avoid the problem. Though if later code goes to consume the entity that was updated there will be no navigation property populated, so for instance anywhere you might want the City.Name you have to check if City is #null and fetch it explicitly. For simple lookups, things like statuses etc. I recommend using enum PK/FK where I have a status table for ref. integrity, but no entity/navigation property.